# Attempted import error: 'Space' is not exported from 'antd'

Tags: reactjs, antd

i'm using the following import statement;

```
import { Space } from 'antd'
```

and receiving the following error:

```
 Attempted import error: 'Space' is not exported from 'antd'
```

not sure what the issue is. please help.

Comment: have you checked your ant version? this component is developed in v4.